# The Facebook POST Object - Android

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am making a **Birthday Reminder Facebook Application**, in which i am *allowing user to post message on friend's wall*, here i am *providing a fixed Image and a Text message to post*.

Still i have given text in Strings.xml like below:

```
  <string name="app_action">Wishing you a birthday as special as you are! Hope this is a new beginning to lots of great things and happy moments in your life. Wish you a fabulous birthday!</string>
```

and ImageLink like this:

```
  public static final String ICON_URL = "http://i1.pickupflowers.com/images/puf/images/product/large/carnations-lilies-and-roses.jpg";
```

But now i **want to allow user to select an image from multiple images and also select message from multiple messages** to post on wall...

[image]

Like in above image, where written

> **link and name** - here i want to show multiple messages and want to allow user to choose one of them to post on wall
>
> **picture** - here i want to show multiple images and allow user to select one of them...

now my question is how can i do this....should i use webservice or any other way, like i want to make these two things more dynamic, like if in future i need to add more messages and images, so i don't want to make it programmatically like by using XML or JSON Parser...

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts But be aware, posting using pre-filled message is against FB Platform Policies. You are only supposed to post what the user typed in themselves.

Answer (score 0):

As is mantioned by @CBroe, *posting using pre-filled message is against FB Platform Policies. You are only supposed to post what the user typed in themselves*. But to make it clear, you need to use facebook's API, and in order to do that you need to run a webservice witch is hosted somewhere. when a user wants to use your app, he/she is redirected to facebooks app page, witch runs an iframe to your service.